# Tableau 9.3 Table Calcuation Customize Option Missing

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Desktop 9.3. I saw on a tutorial that Table Calculation has a Customize option (first graph), however, i couldn't find it on my version? Can someone advise me how can I add it?

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chWNn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INoEr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way this is done has been changed in 9.3 [see this tutorial](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_custom.html)

Hope this helps